# How to transmit UIEvent to UIResponders below

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, uibutton, touch

I have many small `UIButtons` and a large one that covers them all. 
The small `UIButtons` should all react to `UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat` and call a selector. The big UIButton only has to react to UIControlEventTouchDragInside. The big `UIButton` however, consumes all touches, and the `UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat` event doesn't reach the small buttons underneath. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the big `UIButton` is covering the small buttons than the short answer is you can't. Events are passed up the responder chain and when it comes to views the events is passed along to its superview unless the event is handled. Since a view only can have **one** superview what you want to do is not possible, at least not easily.

If you can reverse the layout, having all the small buttons on top of the the big button it could work. I'm not sure if the events would behave as you would like, you just have to test it out. But all the events not handled by a small button should be passed along to the big button.

If you can capture the point that was touched for `UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat` then you should be able to find which small button is below the touch and pass along the event that way. You would have to ask the superview of the small buttons, which perhaps is the same as the superview for the big button?, for the view at the touched coordinate and the do something to that view.

Possibly you would want to look into an alternative solution, perhaps creating a custom control that handles the touches as you want.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I will try reversing the layout and just pass any event different than UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat to the next view and come back with feedback. About the custom control, you mean setting up an UIResponder on top of everything and let it take all necessary actions?